# Add New Object Entity Framework. One to Many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I have Users and Persons table. One user has many persons. When I add new Person to already existing user **do I have to retrieve user object and add new Person to it or is it enough to specify userid to person object?**

```
public void InsertUpdatePerson(int? personId, string firstName, string lastName,
            string middleName, DateTime dob, string mobile, string email, int userid)
        {
            using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
            {
                Person pers;
                if (personId.HasValue)
                {
                    pers = context.People.Where(p => p.PersonID == personId).FirstOrDefault();
                    pers.FirstName = firstName;
                    pers.LastName = lastName;
                    pers.MiddleName = middleName;
                    pers.DOB = dob;
                    pers.Mobile = mobile;
                    pers.Email = email;
                    pers.UserID = userid;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In this scenario, I typically retrieve the user and then add Person and saveChanges, but I am not certain what you MUST do in a minimalistic sense.  Have you tried what you are suggesting? did it throw an exception?

Comment: If you run your code, that should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I use EF 4.3.1 code first and this is not the case. You can simply set the foreign key without requiring retrieval.